# How can I turn on notifications on Facebook for messages only?

Tags: facebook

I would like to receive an email whenever I receive a message on Facebook, but I don't want any other email from Facebook. How shall I configure Facebook settings for that purpose?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is no longer relevant since Facebook do have separate notifications settings for messages.

[image]